# Amplify reset password OTP getting delayed to get in Outlook email account

Tags: angular, aws-lambda, outlook, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I have implemented AWS reset password functionality using Amplify in Angular. I do receive the Reset Code in my outlook account and it works fine later as well to reset the password. The only problem I am facing is that Reset Code takes around 15 mins to come to my outlook email whereas it comes immediately to my Gmail account. Is there a way to minimize this delay or to solve it? Or is there a way to reset password without getting the Reset Code?

We can only use email to reset password because of the company policies. We planned to replace "the 'Forgot Password' functionality using Reset Code" with "deleting the user and creating it again", but again to do so, we need to create an API (to call the lambda - where deleting and creating user functionality sits) which works without Authorization. But doesn't think, it's a optimum way to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried sending these emails with SES? Go to Edit Email Configuration in Cognito and see what you have setup. This might be a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are bound to use our server to send emails and can't use SES. We are using lambda and nodemailer to send the send emails.